# Unable to enter code using Two factor plugin on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

I have just installed https://wordpress.org/plugins/two-factor plugin on my wordpress site and enabled email and google authenticator code. I saved the changes and logged out. Now when I try to login again, after email and password and it shows a `disabled` form that I can't interact. Now I am not able to login. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There seems a bug in this plugin. I inspected the form and inside form element, there was an input type `submit` element. Which was disabled. I removed its disabled css property and form was intractable. I was able to enter code and login.
Deleted this plugin. Will try another one.